# How to create an image that displays email numbers on top in Compose

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose

so I am trying to create an email display image, my challenge is, in compose I don't know how I can make the email display show correctly on my image. See my code below.

This is what I want to achieve

How can I get a similar shape.

```
@Composable
fun NumberedIcon(number: Int, iconRes: Int) {
    Box(modifier = Modifier.size(48.dp), contentAlignment = Alignment.Center) {
        Image(
            painter = painterResource(id = iconRes),
            contentDescription = null,
            modifier = Modifier.size(32.dp),
            contentScale = ContentScale.FillBounds,
            alpha = 0.8f
        )
        Box(
            modifier = Modifier
                .graphicsLayer(alpha = 0.8f)
                .size(24.dp)
                .background(Color.White, shape = CircleShape),
            contentAlignment = Alignment.Center
        ) {
            Text(
                text = number.toString(),
                fontSize = 12.sp,
                color = Color.Black
            )
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assigning `Modifier.align(Alignment.TopEnd)` to `Box` that contains `Text` will put it to top end of the parent `Box`

```
@Composable
fun NumberedIcon(number: Int, iconRes: Int) {
    Box(
        modifier = Modifier
            .size(48.dp),
        contentAlignment = Alignment.Center
    ) {

        Image(
            painter = painterResource(id = iconRes),
            contentDescription = null,
            modifier = Modifier
                .size(32.dp),
            contentScale = ContentScale.FillBounds,
            alpha = 0.8f
        )

        Box(
            modifier = Modifier
                .align(Alignment.TopEnd)
                .graphicsLayer(alpha = 0.8f)
                .size(24.dp)
                .background(Color.White, shape = CircleShape),
            contentAlignment = Alignment.Center
        ) {
            Text(
                text = number.toString(),
                fontSize = 12.sp,
                color = Color.Black
            )
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You can also remove `graphicsLayer(alpha = 0.8f)` for it to resemble more in image you shared.